# Ant tokenfilter add string at beginning of each line and remove newlines characters

Tags: regex, ant

I need to load properties from a file and change the string the following way :

```
prop1=value1
prop2=value2

prop3=value3
```

into :

```
-Pprop1=value1 -Pprop2=value2 -Pprop3=value3
```

(Basically I want to add -P in the beginning of each line and remove the newlines)

I have used `tokenfilter` the following way :

```
<loadfile property="temp.properties" srcFile="${properties.file}">
    <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter delimoutput=" -P">
            <ignoreblank />
        </tokenfilter>
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

The problem with this approach is that if, lets say the file ends with empty new lines, I get the following string :

```
prop1=value1 -Pprop2=value2 -Pprop3=value3 -P
```

1. I don't get a `-P` on the first property (nothing has to do with the newlines at the end of the file). This is easy to overcome with Ant by just concatenating a `-P` string with the result string
2. A problem that I need to overcome is the **-P** at the end. Anyone has a suggestion to fix this ?

Also, a nice addition would be to ignore properties comments - lines that start with `#` but if it's complicates stuff too much, it's not important.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following work for you?

```
<filterchain>
  <replaceregex pattern="^[#].*" replace="" />
  <ignoreblank />
  <prefixlines prefix=" -P" />
  <striplinebreaks />
</filterchain>
```

Comment: With a slight adjustment it does exactly what I need. just add `<ignoreblank />` between `<replaceregex>` and `<prefixlines>`. Change the answer and i'll accept it. Thanks !

Comment: According to the docs for replaceregex it should be match and not pattern. See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html